# Подключение OpenSSL к QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, openssl

Можно ли подключить исходники *OpenSSL* к *Qt Creator* таким образом, чтобы можно было использовать их в любом проекте (т.е. не подключая к каждому проекту в отдельности)? И какие вообще существуют способы подключить сторонние библиотеки к проекту на QT?

Comment: 1) Что мешает создать свой шаблон проекта с уже интегрированной либой?
2) Ну видимо qt "многопроектного" решения не имеет, но можно как-то покопать и написать свой плагин для креатора.